# For some reason my media query switched my original mobile-first design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Im working on this responsive website [(hosted site)](https://davon286.github.io/yummy.eats/). If you use the inspect tool, it looks fine on desktop/tablet versions, but on the mobile version, the sections are still next to each other. I made this mobile-first so the media query shouldn't have affected the mobile version. To be even more clear the mobile version should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENUN.png)

I posted the code on [github](https://github.com/davon286/yummy.eats), but I believe the relevant code to be:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .authentic {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
        grid-template-areas: 'bowl content';
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .right-col {
        grid-area: content;
        padding: 0 10%;
        text-align: left;
        align-self: center;
    }
img {
    grid-area: bowl;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 50vh;

  }
}
```

I'm new to stack overflow so if i'm missing anything let me know. Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the browser to set the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device with something like this in the head of your index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Wow, rookie mistake haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. As suggested, I added the meta tag but it seems to have messed up the complete layout of the mobile-version. I'm going to try re-creating the mobile view.

Comment: Turns out, it was just the values stored in 'rem', seems to build a new relevance with the 'root' sizing. Hence, only these were needed to be re-done.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing  the viewport meta tag inside the  element of your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```